# Add a number with arrays variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can you please help me to add number to the bellow array:

I need to add `item.y = String(v.Title) + 2` 
if i do this if the result of `item.y` before adding 2 is 8 after adding it will become 82 and not 10 could you please help me solve this issue

```
var list = [];
        LoadService("Char", data, function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.d != null && data.d.length > 0) {
                $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {
                    var item = {};
                    item.y = String(v.Title);
                    item.d = v.faild;
                })
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Instead of String() use Number().

Comment: `8 + 2 = 10`, but `"8" + "2" = "82"`

Comment: You have a property called `Title` that you expect to contain numeric data? Huh?

Comment: Thanks for quick replay, yes im expecting numeric data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = [];
LoadService("Char", data, function (data, status) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.d != null && data.d.length > 0) {
        $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {
            var item = {};
            item.y = parseInt(v.Title) + 2;
            item.d = v.faild;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you its working perfect, Could you please tell me how can i add  :00 to the item.y as well? so if the result after sum is 10 to show 10:00. appreciate

Comment: @Azrahedour: At that point it becomes a string again.  So `item.y + ":00"`

Comment: `item.y =  (parseInt(v.Title)+2) + ":00"`

Comment: You can check the answer of @GaneshMatkam :)